# Unable to connect to the mongodb instance running in a docker container from inside the container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, azure-functions

I have built a docker container consisting of a mongodb database and an azure http-triggered function. The following yaml is the docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 37017:27017
  storage.emulator:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite:latest"
    container_name: storage.emulator
    ports: 
      - 20000:10000
      - 20001:10001
      - 20002:10002
  my.functions:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myfunctions
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: domain/My.Functions/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 9080:80
    depends_on: 
      - storage.emulator
      - mongo
```

The mongodb instance runs well and I am able to connect to it from outside of the container by `mongodb://localhost:37017` connection string to seed some data.

The Azure Function running inside the container is supposed to communicate with the mongodb instance by `mongodb://localhost:27017` connection string but it fails according to the following error message:

> "Unspecified/localhost:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State:
> "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown",
> HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An
> exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
> my.functions_1  |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99):
> Cannot assign requested address

How can I address this problem? Why the mongodb is unavailable internally to the azure function within the same container?

Comment: try to use VM's private ip instead of localhost.

Comment: what that prive ip would be?

Comment: I am not sure. what did you mean by "outside of the container". is it your pc or web console or something ?

Btw problem is probably the mongo and your azure function runs on different docker-network. so you cant access mongo by its service name neither you cant access it via localhost.

Comment: @m303945 I shared the entire docker compose file in the post. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because docker containers runs on isolated networks of their own. So when you try to connect localhost, actually you are trying to my.functions app and obviously it does not have service running on that part.

You should use docker-compose service name

mongodb://mongo:27017

Comment: Frankly, I am pretty much novice to docker world. The goal is to prepare a container and share it with other team members. How can I ensure that /etc/mongod.conf.orig file is altered properly whenever "docker compose up" is run? Should I ask the end users to change that file everytime?

Comment: I also modified /etc/mongod.conf.orig per your advice and the result was not conclusive. I still see the same error message.

Comment: how you run this docker-compose file ? from where ? A VM

Comment: No, from a laptop.

Comment: It worked, but I did not have to replace bindIp and left it as is. So, mongodb://mongo:27017 suffices to address the issue.

Comment: Glad I can help.

Comment: This issue just happened when using dotnet-isolated Azure Function Apps (.net 6.0 and azure function v4). Any idea what may be contributing? In terms of docker-compose file nothing changed and then only change is migrating the app to .net 6.0.